# How to Use window function to get minimum value for bunch of groups but grouped in inplace sorted manner

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata, window-functions

I have a table say customer

| DATE | ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | FI |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | LF |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | LF |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | FI |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | LF |

Now what I want to do is add a new column ' NEW_DATE ' in which I have a logic as follows:

```
if type = FI then set it NULL
Else if LF then take the lowest Date which is following the continuous order
```

Expected output:

| DATE | ID | TYPE | NEW_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | FI | NULL |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | LF | 2019-01-01 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | LF | 2019-01-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | FI | NULL |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | LF | 2022-01-01 |

In this the2nd and  3rd row have continuous LF code so it will take the lowest date i.e, 2019-01-01 and in the 4rth FI is there so null and chain breaks. So 5th Row gets 2022-01-01

Now I want to use window function like

```
CASE 
    WHEN TYPE <> 'LF' 
        THEN NULL
        ELSE MIN(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY DATE) 
END AS NEW_DATE
```

but this considers all types as one whole. So what can be the solution to this?

Comment: SQL Server or Teradata?

Comment: Any will work..!

Comment: can you share the results of your query

Comment: FI all null and 2019-01-01 in all LF as its taking all LF as one group and giving the Minimum Date. But what I want is just to take one bunch of LF groups and give me the Min Date for that Bunch If it makes sense

Comment: you mean two consecutives LF should have same minimum date but no the later one

Comment: Exactly. For all consecutive LF's the New_date should be the Minimum date of Just those consecutive groups. So as the 4rth row has FI the the chain is broken and 5th is now itself a new group so 5th row will take date as minimum of itself

Comment: Not only two consecutive LF's but any no. of continuous Lf Groups.

Comment: I removed the SQL Server 2008 tag.  Not only is the product no longer supported, but your sample code would not run in that database.

Comment: Do you have any other incremental id column which defines the order so that you can get a subset of Lfs based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you need, you need to define a group for each block of types and then get the minimum date per block:

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem. In the CTE we assign an incrementing row number for only type LF, and subtract from it a row number for all rows, this results in the same value for consecutive types. This then provides the mechanism to partition/group by in order to get the minimum date per block of consecutive types.

```
with grouped as (
select id, date, type, 
     case when type='LF' then Row_Number() over (partition by id, type  order by date) end -Row_Number()  over (partition by id order by date) gp
from customer
)
select date, id, type, 
    case when type='LF' then Min(date) over(partition by gp) end New_Date
from grouped
order by date
```

Comment: Thanks much stu. I think it works but i need to understand it how

Comment: @stu can you please provide some description

Comment: ooh nice. now i got it

Comment: I have edited and added a bit more explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'LF' 
      THEN MIN(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'FI' THEN DATE END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) 
 END) AS NEW_DATE
```

I added the `PARTITION BY ID` because I'm guessing that you want this per `ID`.  If not, then remove the `PARTITION BY` clause.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=15022dbdf7c340c6e54a407f1ed0ff0c) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

I misunderstood the question.  You seem to want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when type = 'LF'
             then max(case when type = 'LF' and (prev_type is null or prev_type <> type)
                           then date
                      end) over (partition by id order by date)
        end) as lf_date
from (select t.*,
             lag(type) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_type
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Nope. this is giving me 2018-01-01 for all LF's

Comment: @Ishaan . . . I fixed a typo and added a DB Fiddle.

Comment: I see the value of 5th row is NULL. But if you check the expected output it should have 2022-01-01 as the New_Date

Comment: Also I want to pick the Lowest Date in a continuous groups of LF's .Please check the desired output above